# How much faster is Python 2.7's new IO library compared to earlier versions?

Tags: python, io, python-2.7

The Python 2.7 [update note](http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/2.7.html#python-3-1-features) says:

> A new version of the io library, rewritten in C for performance.

I've played with Python 2.7 a bit, but I don't see any performance gain:

```
>>> from timeit import Timer
>>> t = Timer('f = open("E:\\db.txt", "r"); f.read(); f.close()')
>>> t.timeit(10000)
```

And the result:

> - Python 2.6.5 -- 12.879124022745913
> - Python 2.7   -- 12.905614540395504

Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Try your tests line-by-line and char-by-char for more variety.

Comment: Huh. I tried a few things and Py3k is generally two orders of magnitude slower. /me/confused/

Comment: Which version of py3k are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at http://docs.python.org/library/io.html, the `open()` method in the `io` module isn't used by default for opening files in python 2.x. It was only in python 3.x which makes `open()` use `io.open()`.

Try:

```
from timeit import Timer
t = Timer('f = io.open("E:\\db.txt", "r"); f.read(); f.close()', 'import io')
t.timeit(10000)
```

Comment: Oops, I was looking at the Python 3.2 docs. Looks like I've also misread the sentence. It's the Python 3 IO library (with Unicode as the default codec) has been back-ported to Python 2.7. The default IO in Python 2.x is already written in C and has decent performance.

Comment: >>>t = Timer('f = io.open("E:\\db.txt", "r"); f.read(); f.close()', 'import io')  --> I get 30.724059342737746, similar to Python 3.x